# Is it possible to return superclass object from initialized subclass without initializing superclass

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class Person
{
    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;
    final int age;
    final UUID identification;

    public Person(final String firstName, final String lastName, final int age)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.identification = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    protected Person(final String firstName, final String lastName, final int age, final UUID identification)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.identification = identification;
    }

    /*
        Getter functions 
    */

    public Person asPerson()
    {
        return this;
    }

    /*
        Hash and Equals code
        Equals checks for first/lastName, age, and identification
    */
}

public class Employee extends Person
{
    final String occupation;
    final float salary;

    public Employee(final String firstName, final String lastName, final int age, final String occupation, final float salary)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName, age);
        this.occupation = occupation;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Employee(final Person person, final String occupation, final float salary)
    {
        super(person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName, person.getAge(), person.getID());
        this.occupation = occupation;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    /*
        Getter functions for occupation and salary
    */

    @Override
    public Person asPerson()
    {
        return new Person(firstName, lastName, age, identification);
    }

    /*
        Hash and Equals code
        Equals checks for equality in occupation and salary
    */
}

public class Volunteer extends Person
{
    final String location;

    public Volunteer(final String firstName, final String lastName, final int age, final String location)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName, age);
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Volunteer(final Person person, final String location)
    {
        super(person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName(), person.getAge(), person.getID());
        this.location = location;
    }

    /*
        Getter for location
    */

    @Override
    public Person asPerson()
    {
        return new Person(firstName, lastName, age, identification);
    }

    /*
        Hash and Equals
        Equals checks for equality in location.
    */
}

public Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Person person = new Person("Man", "Fredman", 25);
        final Person employee = new Employee(person, "Driver", 65000.0f);
        final Person volunteer = new Volunteer(person, "Philly");

        final boolean eqality = compareVtoE(volunteer, employee);

        System.out.println(equality);
    }

    private boolean compareVtoE(final Person volunteer, final Person employee)
    {
        return volunteer.asPerson().equals(employee.asPerson());
    }
}
```

Having an `Employee` variable already defined, is there a way in the `asPerson` function in `Employee` to return the superclass instance without having to call `new Person(...)`?

My current work-around is using a protected constructor to take in `identification`, but I would think there is a better way to go about this.

**Edit**

I have expanded the example. Say I have a `Volunteer` and an `Employee` that both extends `Person` and can take in a `Person` object in the constructor. They can both be the same person, but do different things. To see if one volunteer is the same as an employee, I need a way to get the `Person` object, without changing the UUID. My work-around is using a protected constructor in `Person` that takes in the UUID, used in the subclass constructors with `super`. I want to avoid using the constructor in `asPerson()`, creating a new instance of `Person`.

Comment: If `Employee` is-a `Person`, then why do you need to override `asPerson()` in `Employee`? I suspect the root issue here is that you're violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) somehow.

Comment: Or perhaps to put it another way: why is it OK for `Person::asPerson()` to return `this`? If the semantic is that `asPerson()` should create a new object with an independent identity, it should call the protected constructor itself, and then `Employee` still wouldn't need to override it.

Comment: Why do you need the `asPerson()` method at all? Since `Employee` extends `Person`, you can directly assign an `Employee` object to a variable of type `Person`: `Person p = new Employee(...);`. An `Employee` *is a* `Person`. No need to convert.

Comment: @DanielPryden `Employee::asPerson()` should be responding with the object of `Person` and not `Employee` that extends `Person`. Should a `Person` object slip in, `Person::asPerson()` helps mitigate possible errors when comparing any subclasses with each other. It also is a way to avoid creating a new object when it already exists.

Comment: @Jesper Should `Person p = new Employee(...)` exists, and I need a `Person` object, not `Employee`, to compare to other subclasses that extend `Person`, then I need a way to get `Person` without the extras attached in `Employee`.

Comment: @CodeMonkey can you show us an example of the situation you're trying to avoid? In what circumstance would the "extras attached to `Employee`" prevent you from comparing an `Employee` object to a `Volunteer` object, for example?

Comment: This would only be a problem if the same person can be two things at the same time - perhaps both an Employee and a Volunteer - otherwise you would never have a problem comparing different subclasses. If that's the case, then an inheritance hierarchy isn't the proper way to model this. Rather, in that case, you are talking about roles that a Person has. You can model that with an attribute `Set<Role> roles` in `Person`.

Comment: I think I asked this question before I fully knew what I was trying to ask and before thinking it out on my own, only to realize while editing to add the expanded example that what I was trying to ask cannot be accomplished in the way that I was wanting it to be done.

Comment: do you want something like: return (Person) this;

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there is no way to do what you are asking for as it would require changing the object without changing it, but here are two possible solutions to your comparison problem:

1. Override the `equals` method in `Person` class so you can compare people regardless of their role (employee or volunteer):

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
       if (other instanceof Person) {
           return identification.equals(((Person)other).identification);
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```
2. If for some reason you can not use `equals`, for example you need to override it in derived classes with different functionality, just create a `isSamePerson` function like this:

   ```
   public boolean isSamePerson(Person other) {
       if (other != null) return identification.equals(other.identification);
       return false;
   }
   ```

This will save you unnecessary object duplication, and the danger of loosing track of the people.